# CLR fails on first use due to unused variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I have a situation in which a completely unused variable causes an error.  Removing the unused variable declaration clears the error.  Once cleared, the error stays cleared (even if the unused variable is restored) until SQL Server is restarted, at which point it returns.

I have defined a CLR function and a table-valued UDF.  I can call the CLR using this test-case code:

```
Declare @name_does_not_matter Table (any_column_name int);

Select dbo.MapTesseractUris(
    N'<a href="tesseract:2">map this uri</a>',
    N'localhost:6313');
```

Doing so results in this error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MapTesseractUris": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpSmiRequest(SqlInternalConnectionSmi innerConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Tesseract.Database.TesseractUri.MapPageIdsToUrls(IEnumerable`1 pageIds, String forDomain)
   at Tesseract.Database.TesseractUri.MapTesseractUris(String html, String forDomain)
```

The error is occurring at the point in my code where the CLR calls the UDF.  Calling the UDF directly does not result in an error.

However, if I call the CLR using this code instead, I get the correct, expected result:

```
Select dbo.MapTesseractUris(
    N'<a href="tesseract:2">map this uri</a>',
    N'localhost:6313');
```

Once I get a successful execution, further executions will always work without error.  I can restore the missing `Declare` statement and not get an error.  I can alter the input parameters and not get the error.

I can cause the error to return by restarting SQL server or by dropping and redeploying the entire database.

In case it is not obvious, the `@name_does_not_matter` table variable is not used anywhere.  This must be a table variable to cause the problem (`Declare @name_does_not_matter int` does not cause issues).

What could be causing this?

How can I resolve this, without resorting to executing the "fixing" SQL every time SQL Server restarts?

**Update**

Here is the requested code of `Tesseract.Database.TesseractUri.MapPageIdsToUrls`:

```
private static IDictionary<int, string> MapPageIdsToUrls(
    IEnumerable<int> pageIds,
    string forDomain)
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) {
        db.Open();

        using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = @"
                Select [Id], [Url]
                From [dbo].[ResolvePageUrls](@pageIds, @domain)";

            var p = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                "@pageIds",
                CreateDataRecords(pageIds));

            p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            p.TypeName = "dbo.IntTable";

            cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@domain", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 252)
                .Value = forDomain;

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                return reader.OfType<IDataRecord>()
                    .Select(row => Tuple.Create(
                        row.GetInt32(0),
                        row.GetValue(1) as string))
                    .ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateDataRecords(
    IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var metaData = new[] { new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Int) };
    var record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
    foreach (var id in ids.Distinct()) {
        record.SetInt32(0, id);
        yield return record;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a coincidence and maybe there is an error inside your SqlClr stuff?  Your error stack seems to indicate that the error is happening inside of your CLR code, during some ExecuteReader().  Is it possible that you have a temp table or connection or something else that tries to clean up leftovers from the last run (which won't exist on the first run).

Comment: I do not believe this is the case. I am not using any temp tables. I am only using the context connection. All `IDisposable` objects are wrapped in `using` statements. The CLR is doing some Regexp find-and-replace and string manipulation.  There does not seem to be anything to clean up.

Comment: The last statement in the error stack comes from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection...  Could you post your SqlClr code for Tesseract.Database.TesseractUri.MapPageIdsToUrls(), up to the ExecuteReader() line.

Comment: Updated with the requested code!

Comment: Have you decorated your method with the `SqlFunction` attribute. For example, [SqlFunction(
       DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
       FillRowMethodName = "FindInvalidEmails_FillRow",
       TableDefinition="CustomerId int, EmailAddress nvarchar(4000)")]

Comment: BTW, I think the methods should be `public static` not `private static`.

Comment: The method I posted, `MapPageIdsToUrls` is called within the CLR by another method, named `MapTesseractUris`.  The `MapTesseractUris` method is indeed decorated with `[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read, IsDeterministic = true)]`.

Comment: You should probably debug and test the procedure with the help of a debugger (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql%20clr%20debugging). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that process. I also can see that you're calling ResolvePageUrls. This function might be involved as well.

Comment: When debugging, the debugger detaches itself at the point at which the error would be thrown.  Execution seems to stop entirely.  I do not see the error, but I do not see the results either.  I assume the error is happening in such a way that it causes the debugger to fail.  Everything up until the `ExecuteReader()` statement seems to be normal.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Did you ever solve this? I think it has to do with the use of the TVP when calling the `ResolvePageUrls` TVF. I am thinking these things are related since TVPs are table variables, and maybe having one declared messes with how the TVP handling grabs an available temporary name or something (since they do exist in `tempdb`). Had you tested to see if the error would occur if you inserted a single row into that table variable? Also, you should probably mark this method as `IsDeterminstic=false` since it does data access, unless that TVF will return consistent results for same input.